# Cannot find module vertx/console

Tags: javascript, vert.x

I have installed vertx 3 on windows 10 with java 1.8 installed.and i set the variable PATH to include path into bin Vertx  directory 
When i try to run this simple Verticle :

> var console = require("vertx/console");
>   console.log("Hello world");
>   I am getting the following error :
>   javax.script.ScriptException: Error: Cannot find module vertx/console in  >at line number 141 at column number 6
>          at >jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScr>iptEngine.java:455)
>          at >jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java>:439)
>          at >jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java>:401)

Comment: AFAIK, require works from the location you are running the JS from - not from the PATH (unless they overlap, if course). Or was it from the HOME of the engine? One of those :)

Comment: When i switch to vertx 2 it works fine!!!

Answer (score 0):

With the advent of *vert.x 3*, it's no longer necessary to use the `require` statement.  You can simply write:

```
console.log("Hello world");
```